# How to Find and delete File Older than 3 years?

Tags: linux, terminal

I'm new with server maintenance job.

Now I must find and delete .JPG File older than 3 years. on linux terminal

I have googled and found a script like this

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +365 -exec rm {} \;

or

find /path/to/files* -mtime +365 -delete;
```

I have tried this

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +1095 -exec rm {} \;

or

find /path/to/files* -mtime +1095 -delete;
```

But it didn't work, I think my file is too big to be found.

Can anyone help me to fix this..?

Or maybe there's another way?

I would appreciate your answer a lot.

Thanks

Comment: find has nothing to do with file size, and should be able to "find" any file for you. How is it "not working"? Any error messages? Try a find /path/ -mtime +1095 -exec ls {} \; to get a list of the files, and see if that works...

Comment: ok I will try you advice, but  when i try this find /path/to/files* -mtime +1095 and enter on terminal, nothing show and nothing error.

Comment: I have try your advice ind /srv/www/htdocs/c-app/fkendaraan/ -mtime +1095 -exec ls {} \; and nothing happen.

Comment: So there's nothing older than 3 years then.

Comment: @drookie 
So there's nothing older than 3 years then. ok I know, my issue is, Im Sure that my Data Older than 5 year. but, I have resync it to new server. And the data maybe change date when I resync. is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this command:

## find /path/to/files -mtime +1095 -type f -name "*.JPG" -delete

Is important that you put the *-delete* parameter at the end.

(From man page of find command: *"...Don't  forget  that the find command line is evaluated as an expression, so putting -delete first will make find try to delete everything below the starting points you specified..."*

first to run that you should check the output running:

## find /path/to/files -mtime +1095 -type f -name "*.JPG"

(Whithout *-delete*)

*find* will search into */path/to/files* everything with metadata changed more than 1095 days ago (*-mtime +1095*), then

*-type f* 
will restrict the search only to files type,

-name "*.JPG"
Only the files with de JPG extension will be selected
and

*-delete* will delete everything that was finded (without ask you for conferm your will).

I hope this can help you.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but after try this find /path/to/files -mtime +1095 -type f -name "*.JPG"  nothing happen. I think date file change when I resync to new server